# I am am trying to add or remove a string into form field depending on when the user clicks on a certain part of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#showrightcornerbumper").click(function(){
         $("#first").toggle();
     });
 });
 </script>
 
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#showleftcornerbumper").click(function(){
         $("#second").toggle();
     });
 });
 </script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#backbumper").click(function(){
         $("#third").toggle();
     });
 });
 </script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#boot").click(function(){
         $("#fourth").toggle();
     });
 });
 </script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#leftrearquaterpanel").click(function(){
         $("#fifth").toggle();
     });
 });
 </script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#rightrearquaterpanel").click(function(){
         $("#sixth").toggle();
         
     });
 });
 </script>

 <script>
  $(function () {
      $("#showleftcornerbumper").on("click", function () {
          var text = $("#text");
          text.val(text.val() + " an estimate for this type of repair would be €200");    
      });
  });
 </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/car.png" usemap="#carmap">

 <map name="carmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="30,282,50,302" id="showleftcornerbumper" href="#"  alt="Left corner bumper" alt="Left Corner Bumper">
  <area shape="rect" coords="230,282,247,300" id="showrightcornerbumper" href="#" alt="Right Corner Bumper">
  <area shape="rect" coords="91,301,187,306" id="backbumper" href="#" alt="Back Bumper">
  <area shape="rect" coords="93,267,187,297" id="boot" href="#" alt="Boot">
  <area shape="rect" coords="53,250,76,297" id="leftrearquaterpanel" href="#" alt="Left rear quater panel">
  <area shape="rect" coords="202,251,226,299" id="rightrearquaterpanel" href="#" alt="Right rear quater panel">
 </map>
 

 <p id="first" style="display:none;">The cost of this repair is €200.</p>
 <p id="second" style="display:none;">The cost of this repair is €300.</p>
 <p id="third" style="display:none;">The cost of this repair is €300.</p>
 <p id="fourth" style="display:none;">The cost of this repair is €300.</p>
 <p id="fifth" style="display:none;">The cost of this repair is €300.</p>
 <p id="sixth" style="display:none;">The cost of this repair is €300.</p>

<form action="action_page.php">
   First name:<br>
   <input type="text" value="">
   <br>
   Email:<br>
   <input type="Email" name="lastname" value="" id="email">
   <br>
   Quote:<br>
   <input type="text" value="Thank you for your interest in Smart Repair" id="text" size="100" />
 <br />
 <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
</form>
```

im trying to recreate a repair calculator similar to the following https://revive-uk.com/get-a-quick-quote/ , i am going around in circles, i have basic html,css, jquery and js knowledge . I want to be able to highlight different parts of the car by clicking on  the area or toggle on and off. after reading the forum i believe its best to do it from a single image.

Comment: Can do this fairly easily with an image map and maphighlighter plugin or convert to svg. Google searches should have been able to produce various approaches

Comment: hi! please ask questions with code exmaples

Comment: A nice way would be to use SVG and modify it on the fly with jQuery

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the task you took upon yourself is quite complex - the site you've included uses SVG images & animations with javascript in order to create the quote.

have you tried anything? please include your code in the question.

i would not recommend using a single picture because you'd have to use image maps (try a little in here if you'd like to get the sense of it: https://www.image-maps.com/) , but SVG's are hard to master when early developer.

IMHO, try splitting the car's image to different images / areas, than build a form with Jquery taking values from some data attributes - and than continue with it to give the quote based on some calculator.

Comment: i have tried the image maps but im getting confused as i dont want to create a link to link out, i just want to high light the area first, if i can independently select different parts of the car i would be happy

Comment: @Eoin the site you've included uses SVGs, that's how the hover/highlight options work here. i dont think that you can manipulate an existing image with image maps. have you tried working with SVGs?

Comment: for example if i save that image as an SVG file, would i be able to map the outline using image maps, or am i completely out of my debt in your opinion.

Comment: i think that you are over complicating the issue. saving each part in  a different image and displaying them in seperate div / row would benefit you grately. image maps & SVGs are hard to handle, moreover as a beginner developer

Comment: ok i understand mouse overs, from what i understand about a mouse over is it will highlight or change the full image, is there a way to mouse over the car bonnet and it displays a price A, then if i mouse over the door it displays price 2. or does mouse over only work with the full image, sorry for all the questions

Comment: Guys, I just posted the exact library these guys used on website OP linked. It's pretty easy to use, no need to go using tons of images.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, I've found that the site you linked uses [Raphaël](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) library, which allows you to add SVG objects and modify them from JavaScript. Example from the website:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
```

Comment: Had a look at this, didnt understand it, so i mapped the coordinates and used Jquery to display a paragraph, i was trying to get Jquery to insert the  string into an input field but the toggle function doesn't seem to work it is removing the entire field instead of the text.